# Is there a way to show when the data in a Data Studio report was last refreshed?

Tags: looker-studio

I know it shows up at the bottom, but would be cool if I was able to show this more visually on the report it's self.

Answer (score 3):

One way that it could be achieved is by using the [`CURRENT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698726) function, which would be updated each time the Report is refreshed; by default, the [`CURRENT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698726) displayed is based on the `UTC` Time Zone; a specific Time Zone or Location could be set, for example to display the [`CURRENT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9698726) in Colombo, Sri Lanka, the following [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) does the trick:

```
CURRENT_DATETIME("Asia/Colombo")
```

Adding the below from an [Earlier Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193189/12892553):
*[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5d6757e8-211e-4743-80a6-d84c99b83262) and a GIF to elaborate*:

[image]