# Is there a way to dynamic Date Time each minute in Google Data Studio without refresh report?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to create a simple report to get the current date and time when viewers see the report without refresh. But I am getting the current date-time when the report generated or refresh the report not when the viewer viewed **(current_datetime)** our report.

```
CURRENT_DATETIME('Asia/Kolkata')
```

[Is there a way to add the current timestamp to a Google Data Studio report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211728/is-there-a-way-to-add-the-current-timestamp-to-a-google-data-studio-report)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to force the report to update every time it is open.

However, you can schedule it to refresh every 15 minutes.

[image: Data freshness location]

[image: Data freshenss option]